# Power BI Embedded Access Token Issue

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Trying to embed Power BI dashboard into our Angular application. The issue is that we're getting the ID token instead of access token. Moreover, there's a cross origin issue as well. If we get the token from postman and embed in a sample web page, it works but when we call it within our application, it doesn't work. It give the following error:

**ERROR:**

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"message":"LoadReportFailed","detailedMessage":"Fail to initialize - Could not resolve cluster","errorCode":"403","level":6,"technicalDetails": 
>   {"requestId":"cde7a17e-5baa-454c-8e8b-72e5b9f1307e"}}

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Granted all permissions on the app created on azure. Used implicit grant.

Need the access token instead of ID token.

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Accordin the [official troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-troubleshoot#typical-errors-when-embedding-for-power-bi-users), this error means that "Embed type doesn't match token type". So this probably is a bug in your code. In [Embed Configuration Details](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details) check the value of [`tokenType`](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/enums/_node_modules_powerbi_models_dist_models_d_.tokentype.html) property. It can be either `AAD` or `Embed`. Make sure it matches the type of the token, that you provided in `accessToken` property.

AAD tokens are acquired when authenticating against Azure AD (usually by calling some [AcquireTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) method). You can use them to access all reports that your user has access to, and to make Power BI REST API calls.

Embed tokens are acquired by calling [GenerateTokenInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup) or other similar method. They are valid for a specific object (e.g. only this one report) and are the recommended way to embed Power BI elements in your application, but they require a capacity (Power BI Premium or Embedded) assigned to your workspace.